# How to specify a proxy in transformers pipeline

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am using sentiment-analysis pipeline as described [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/quicktour.html).

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
```

It's failing with a connection error message

> ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.

Is there a way to specify a proxy within the pipeline method so that it's able to connect to the internet and download the files needed?

Comment: Could you please try it with `proxies={'http': 'foo.bar:3128', 'http://hostname': 'foo.bar:4012'}`? In case that is not working, you need to initialize the tokenizer and the model by yourself with this parameter (I can show you how to do it, in case the other option is not working).

Comment: Tried the proxies option. At least it didn't throw any syntax error but I still kept getting connection error while running the model. May be some network restriction I am not able to figure. I ended up manually downloading config.json, pytorch_model.bin, vocab.txt in a local folder called 'cached_model' and passed that as model = './cached_model' inside the pipeline function.

Comment: Maybe they are not forwarding the proxy settings properly. Could you please try to `m = DistilBertModel.from_retrained('distilbert-base-uncased', proxies={'http': 'foo.bar:3128', 'http://hostname': 'foo.bar:4012'})`?

Answer (score 5):

It should be proxy problem. You can try add this code snippet to go through proxies.

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://xxx:xxx@xxx:xxx'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'http://xxx:xxx@xxx:xxx'

from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
```

**Note:** Remember to use **http** instead of **https** for the proxy value.